# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. I am making a little game with 2D zombies but an error is displayed when I run the code. I searched and tried everything but nothing worked.
Here is a part of the main code:

```
for shuriken in game.player.all_projectile:
    shuriken.move()
```

Here is a part of game.py code:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_monster = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.all_player = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(self)
        self.all_player.add(self.player)

    def check_collision(self, sprite, group):
        return pygame.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False)
```

And here is the code of projectile.py(the error report the last line of this code):

```
class Shuriken(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, player, velocity, x):
        super().__init__()
        self.player = player
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/shuriken.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (40, 40))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = player.rect.x + x
        self.rect.y = player.rect.y + 30
        self.velo_adaptation = self.rect.x
        self.origin_image = self.image
        self.angle = 1

    def rotate(self):

        self.angle += -5
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.origin_image, self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def delete(self):
        self.player.all_projectile.remove()


    def move(self):
        self.rect.x = self.velo_adaptation
        self.velo_adaptation += self.velocity
        self.rotate()
        for zombie in self.player.game.check_collision(self, self.player.game.all_monster):
            self.delete()
            zombie.damage(self.player.attack)

        if self.rect.x > 1080:
            self.delete()
```

(Edit)And here is the zombie class:

```
class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game):
        super().__init__()
        self.health = 100
        self.game = game
        self.max_health = 100
        self.damage = 5
        self.image = pygame.image.load('assets/zombie.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (150, 150))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 950
        self.rect.y = 550
        self.velocity = 0.2

    def damage(self, attack):
        self.health -= attack
        self.update_health_bar()

    def update_health_bar(self, surface):

        bar_color = (113, 206, 45)
        bar_position = [self.rect.x + 30, self.rect.y + -10, self.health, 5]
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, bar_color, bar_position)

    def forward(self):

        if not self.game.check_collision(self, self.game.all_player):
```

Comment: You left out the code that could make this more than psychic debugging, but almost certainly `zombie.damage` is an instance attribute bound to an `int`. You might have *also* defined a method on the class named `damage`, but if you did, you name-shadowed it by assigning to `.damage` on an instance as well, making `zombie.damage` refer to the `int` from then on, not the method.

Comment: This is literally impossible to answer because you haven't given the most important part of your code - the `Zombie` class...

Comment: OK I have update the question. There is the class zombie now(sorry if there are mistakes i don't speak english well ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Zombie(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        ...
        self.damage = 5

    def damage(self, attack):
        ...
```

The `Zombie` class has conflicting definitions for the `damage` attribute.  It can't be both an integer and a function.  Rename one of them.

Comment: Hey, [my psychic debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72078864/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable#comment127357426_72078864) was validated once again!